# Is there a way to easily only allow a subset of azure functions to run when debugging locally in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I'm using Visual Studio to write a class library which contains several Azure functions.  There is a combination of timer and queue triggered functions.  If I'm working on one of the functions and want to debug only it I have to comment out the other functions to keep them also from executing.  Is there a way to easily indicate that I only want a subset of the entire set of functions to execute when debugging locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the [`Disable()` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749508/disable-property-of-azure-functions-not-working-in-visual-studio-2017/45752407#45752407), however, that's not much better than commenting out code:

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *"), Disable()]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
```

You could combine the `Disable()` attribute with `#if` directive, but it clutters up your code. The `Disable()` attribute will only be applied if DEBUG is defined.

The following function will run if in release mode, and is disabled if in debug mode.

```
    [FunctionName("TimerFunction")]
    public static void Run([
        #if DEBUG 
            TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *"), Disable()
        #else
            TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")
        #endif
        ]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you can also add it to the FunctionName attribute which seems a bit cleaner than to the attributes decorating the function parameters. [FunctionName("TimerFunction"), Disable()]

Comment: doesnt that disable is ALL the time, not just release mode?

Comment: You can just do this: 
#if DEBUG
[Disable()]
#endif

Answer (score 5):

You can configure which functions to load in your host.json ([full spec here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functions)) Specifically, you'll want to define a top-level functions property:

```
{
    "functions": [ "QueueProcessor", "GitHubWebHook" ]
}
```

(Note this is only meant for local use; you'll want to use the *function.json* disabled property for published functions.)

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate your function with a DisableAttribute controlled by a settingName from the local.settings.json file.

The following is an example:

```
[QueueTrigger("%queueName%", Connection = "queues"), Disable("MyFuncABC")]ProcessMessage msg,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which functions to disable when running locally by listing them in the [local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function?tabs=portal#localsettingsjson).  NOTE: the local.settings.json should have `<CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobs.MyTimerFunction.Disabled": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you'd then have to also write the plumbing to actually disable those functions, or does this automatically disable them somehow?